# Can you use Angular Binding Expression inside HTML retrieved from Service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-sanitizing

I have a html snippet that comes from a mongo db retrieved by an angular service.  This html snippet is then sanitized on my page using the `ng-bind-html` directive from ngSanitize.  I am wondering how I can bind an expression inside the html snippet to the page, so that when I bind the html the binding expression is executing inside the snippet.  For example,  here is my div where my html snippet will be bound to:

```
                <div ng-bind-html="middle_snippet">

                </div>
```

and here is the actual snippet that gets pull from service.

```
    <p>WHY HERRRRO!!! {{myBinding}}</p>
```

And heres my simple controller:

```
    var middleMainContent = $Content.content({slug: "home-bottom-middle"
    }, function () {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(middleMainContent));
        $scope.middle_snippet = middleMainContent.response.content.snippet;
        $scope.myBinding = 'VERY NICE BINDING';

    });
```

So really my expected results would be the html:

WHY HERRRRO!!! VERY NICE BINDING

However I get the original html with the curly braces.  Any ideas would help as I am at a stand still here trying to get this to work.

---

UPDATE: So after reading about the compile service and using them with directives, as mentioned by Chandermani, I am both enlightened and confused.  The "best practice" way according to AngularJS team when using $compile is to use it within a Directive Definition Object(DDO) as stated here http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile. Ok, so I created a DDO, however, I am confused by what goes into the compile: method for the DDO.  Here is what I have so far:

```
var myModule = angular.module('html_compile');

myModule.directive('html_compiler', function factory(injectables) {
var directiveDefinitionObject = {
    priority: 0,
    template: $scope.snippet,
    replace: true,
    transclude: false,
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: false,
    compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs) {
        return {
            pre: function preLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) { ... },
            post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) { ... }
        }
        // or
        // return function postLink( ... ) { ... }
    },
    // or
    // link: {
    //  pre: function preLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) { ... },
    //  post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) { ... }
    // }
    // or
    // link: function postLink( ... ) { ... }
    };
    return directiveDefinitionObject;
});
```

Comment: You need to compile the content that you receive using $compile service and inject it into html.

Comment: So I need to create custom directive for that too right?

Comment: Look at $compile documentation, At the end there is a compile directive http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Comment: I am starting to read about compile, however, is there a way that ui-router can do this out of the box with a nested view?

Comment: Any content you include using `ui-view` html tag gets automatically compiled in ui view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So @Chandermani hit it on the head with the `$compile` service, and of course it was the example right at the end of that page linked in the comments, however, it was a little confusing since there is a "compile" element inside the Directive Definition Object as listed on the same page.  So I guess this compile element determines how and when you want to compile the directive you are creating within the DDO, and the example at the bottom pertains to the `$compileProvider` and creates a directive off of that.  Blog with fully explained answer is located here: [Your very own $compile service directive](http://brilliantbritz.com/2014/03/18/compiling-html-on-the-fly-via-compileprovider-directive/)