# Angular JS - Binding angular expressions coming from JSON to HTML

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

Is it possible to give angular expression inside a JSON file like this:

```
{
    "headerHTML": "<div>{{clippedCoupons}}</div>"   
}
```

And bind it to a directive template like this (the below convertAsHtml is a filter for trustAsHtml):

```
<header data-ng-bind-html="headerHTML|convertAsHtml">
</header>
```

When I bind the JSON, I'm getting {{clippedCoupons}} expression as such in the page. Is is possible to change it dynamically in our controller?

Comment: Have a look at the [`$interpolate`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate) service

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you use Angular Binding Expression inside HTML retrieved from Service?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22330939/can-you-use-angular-binding-expression-inside-html-retrieved-from-service) - Have a look at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#example

Comment: @Phil/@Reto, When I use it like $interpolate(response.headerHTML)($scope), the initial value of the {{clippedCoupons}} is reflected on my page. But it's not dynamically updating when I perform some action. Whereas, when I use $compile(response.headerHTML)($scope), it throws an error "Attempted to trust a non-string value in a content requiring a string: Context: html". Do we have to use it only in directives?